# flutter: No such Method error while calling close function on timer

Tags: flutter, timer, nullpointerexception, null, gesturedetector

I am using timer class to auto log out after particular time but I am getting the method called on null error
my code for autologout is:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cornershop_tech_1/controller/logOutController.dart';
class AutoLogout{
  logOut logout=new logOut();
  Timer _timer;
  void initializeTimer(context) {
    if (!_timer.isActive) {
      _timer= Timer(Duration(seconds: 300), () {
        print('timer Initialized');
        logout.logOutUser(context); });
    }
    else {
      _timer.cancel();
      _timer= Timer(Duration(seconds: 300), () {
        print('timer Initialized');
        logout.logOutUser(context); });
    }
  }
  bool handleUserInteraction(context,[_]) {
    if (!_timer.isActive) {
      return false;
    }
    _timer.cancel();
    initializeTimer(context);
    return true;
  }
}
```

calling of the function from relevent error causing widget is:

```
AutoLogout autoLogout = new AutoLogout();
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    autoLogout.initializeTimer(context);
    getPrefs();
  }
  void _setAutoLogout([_]){
    autoLogout.handleUserInteraction(context,[_]);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _setAutoLogout,
      onPanDown: _setAutoLogout,
      onScaleStart: _setAutoLogout,
```

The error is:

```
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'b' on null
js_primitives.dart:47     at lr.ku (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:52059:28)
js_primitives.dart:47     at Jk.SN (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:57212:9)
js_primitives.dart:47     at Object.eval (eval at be_ (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:4370:8), <anonymous>:3:37)
js_primitives.dart:47     at a7I.$0 (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:71691:31)
js_primitives.dart:47     at kR.Xl (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:71865:9)
js_primitives.dart:47     at kR.eM (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:71869:30)
js_primitives.dart:47     at kR.a9X (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:71665:3)
js_primitives.dart:47     at kR.jy (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:71603:3)
js_primitives.dart:47     at xZ.acJ (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:93512:14)
js_primitives.dart:47     at Object.eval (eval at be_ (http://localhost:51981/main.dart.js:4370:8), <anonymous>:3:37)
```

`_timer.close()` is giving this error for sure since my code was working absolutely fine before using this function in `_initializeTimer()`  function but I don't know why it's giving this error. I tried removing this `_timer.close()` from `_handleUserInteraction()` but it didn't woorked out.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `isActive` called on timer, when it hasn't been initialized yet.

try this:

```
if (!(_timer?.isActive == true)) {
  _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 300), () {
    print('timer Initialized');
    logout.logOutUser(context); });
}
else {
  _timer?.cancel();
  _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 300), () {
    print('timer Initialized');
    logout.logOutUser(context); });
}
```

Because timer is `nullable` variable all method calls on it should be `null safe`
E.g: timer?.close(), timer?.isActive ... etc

It's better migrate whole project to null safety

Comment: Thanks a lot... that helped ...I can't vote the answer due to reputations